# bash: /usr/local/bin/lli: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, lli

I'm trying to use `lli file.ll` but this error appeared

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/lli: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please, post output of two commands: `file -k /usr/local/bin/lli` and `uname -a`. `lli` may be compiled for different architecture.

Comment: '/usr/local/bin/lli: data'  for 'file -k /usr/local/bin/lli' and 'Linux rasha-Inspiron-N5110 3.19.0-80-generic #88~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 13 14:54:07 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux' for 'uname -a'

Comment: What happens if you just execute `lli --help`? Most likely your `lli` is corrupted.

Comment: Yes, you're right

Comment: I resolve the problem, thank you